# While loop doesn`t detect msvcrt.getch() keypress

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, keypress, msvcrt

```
import msvcrt
x: int = 0
while not msvcrt.getch() == ' ':
    if x <= 10000:
        print(x)
        x += x
    else:
        print("space")
```

Loop is not stopping when the "space" is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

`msvcrt.getch()` returns a bytestring rather than a string so when you press space it will return `b' '`, not `' '`.

Therefore change:

```
while not msvcrt.getch() == ' ':
```

To:

```
while not msvcrt.getch() == b' ':
```

Comment: didn`t change it just flies through 0 not even counting or caring about space key.

Comment: Change `x: int = 0` to `x = 0` and `x+=x` to `x+=1`.

Comment: yes it should have been x += 1 my bad but space is not working still. maybe it not being able to catch it up idk

Comment: After the changes your script works fine for me. It increments x on any button press except space, where it stops.

Comment: import msvcrt
x = 0
while not msvcrt.getch() == b' ':
    if x <= 10000:
        print(x)
        x += 1
    else:
        print("space")

Comment: Yep, works fine as your described. I press space and it prints `space` and exits.

Comment: i am using idle and it doesn`t stop careless of space .

Comment: The Windows console is Unicode (at least for the basic multilingual plane), so it's actually more efficient to use `msvcrt.getwch() == ' '` instead. The performance difference is trivial, but using Unicode supports more characters and is more idiomatic in Python 3. The 'w' in the name indicates it's the [w]ide-character version.

Comment: @RamazanKARADEMİR, `getch` and `getwch` are console functions. They don't work in IDLE unless you manually allocate a console via `AllocConsole`, and even then it requires the console window to have focus.

Answer (score 0):

```
import msvcrt
x = 0
while not msvcrt.getch() == b' ':
    if x <= 10000:
        print(x)
        x += 1
    else:
        print("space")
```

thanks for your interests